# How top stop non Launcher Activities from being destroyed?

Tags: android, android-launcher, back-stack, ondestroy

Lets say I'm starting `Activity B` from `Activity A` which is a `LAUNCHER` Activity. Then, I move app to background and back to foreground. Immediately Activities B `onDestory()` is being called and `onResume()` of A runs then. Is there a way to stop OS from destroying not Launcher Activity on returning to Foreground ?

Activity A Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".login.LoginMethodActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Activity B Manifest :

```
<activity
    android:name=".login.IdentifierConfirmationActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Comment: No, there's no way of stopping that BUT you can use Fragments for that purpose i.e. to keep both objects alive.

Comment: You should tell the whole scenario, the above question not describes; What exactly you want to do. :)

Comment: Simple question : is there a way to return to the activity that was alive before app went to background instead of returning to Launcher activity ?

Comment: You can store the last activity that was alive in sharedPreference and then load from sharedPreference

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try Fragments approach. Seems more logical.